# Android androidx.recyclerview.widget.ListAdapter how to know when all changes done?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

My Adapter extends the [`androidx.recyclerview.widget.ListAdapter`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/recyclerview/extensions/ListAdapter) class  (**not** the android.widget.ListAdapter interface). It works fine, however, when I submit a list with a new item, I need to make the RecyclerView scroll to a specific item, which I do like this:

```
adapter.submitList(entries);
int position = getPosition(entries.get(0));
if (position != NO_POSITION) {
    mListView.smoothScrollToPosition(position);
}
```

This is my method to get the position:

```
    public int getPosition(@Nullable Entry entry) {
        for (int pos = 0; pos < getItemCount(); pos++) {
            if (getItem(pos).equals(entry)) {
                return pos;
            }
        }
        return RecyclerView.NO_POSITION;
    }
```

My problem is, that `getPosition()` when called directly after `submitList()` always return NO_POSITION, because the ListAdapter (which uses an `AsyncListDiffer` to optimize the amount of changes to be made) is not finished when I do my `getPosition()`, so it returns NO_POSITION.

My question is, if there is a way to provide a callback or similar, to learn when all changes to the list are done, so I could do the `getPosition()` and scrolling later.

Comment: [The docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/ListAdapter.html) show a `onCurrentListChanged()` callback, but I think that's in the alpha of the upcoming release.

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks, that sounds promising (I guess I wasn't the only one in need for this). I checked the code and it seems to do exactly what I need. However, when I change my gradle file to use androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0-alpha02, the app doesn't compile anymore and it says that my Activity is not a LifecycleOwner...? I guess I would have to change other libraries as well to higher (alpha) versions?

Comment: I ran into problems with the alpha, and your symptoms sound familiar. In my case, this was for a scrap project, so I just backed away from `ListAdapter`, and I didn't try to debug the problem. Your guess (needing newer versions of other dependencies) seems reasonable.